# Make Android WebView.loadUrl(...) Behave Synchronously

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, synchronous

Has anybody tried to make Android WebView.loadUrl(...) behave synchronously?

My scenario is this: I want to execute some javascript but I don't want to initialize the WebView that executes the javascript until the time at which the javascript is to be executed.  For the javascript to execute successfully the call stack needs to have been prepared.

I need to call loadUrl to load the html page that loads the javascript methods.  The problem is that loadUrl is called and then returns immediately, tearing down the call stack in the process.  Then WebViewClient::onPageFinished(...) gets called later signaling that the WebView is ready and I can execute my script.  But now it is too late because my call stack is gone.

I would like loadUrl to wait for onPageFinished but the problem is that onPageFinished gets called in the same thread as loadUrl was called on (even though the loadUrl happens in another thread).  So waiting after calling loadURL blocks the thread and onPageFinished never gets called.

Is there some pattern in android/java that permits a thread to wait but have the thread's message loop continue to execute so that a notification to that thread can be received?

Comment: What do you care about the call stack? Why not store what you need in data members of the activity or fragment that holds your `WebView`?

Comment: The javascript executes in response to a user event, like a keystroke for example.  The javascript could potentially reject the user input or even modify the user input.

Comment: Then why are you using a `WebView`, instead of a JavaScript engine like Rhino?

Comment: So far, PM has resisted a third party JS engine for the usual reasons: binary size, execution performance, security concerns, permissions, etc.  Using WebView also aligns the Android architecture with our iOS offering where embedding a third party JS engine is prohibited by Apple.

Comment: You act as though you have a choice in the matter. By definition, you cannot block a thread and have the thread run at the same time. Either redesign your app to operate asynchronously, use a JavaScript engine that supports synchronous operation, or get rid of the JavaScript altogether.

Comment: I do not have a choice in whether a 3rd party JS engine is embedded.  This product is literally on hundreds of millions of devices.  There are multiple ways to solve this problem.  I was just wondering if there was a pattern to solve the more general issue I brought up.  I recall Win32 had such a mechanism (WaitForSingleObject) that simulated the behavior I described.  Was wondering if Java had an equivalent.  It sounds like it does not.  So on to plan B.

Comment: did you find a solution?